# Does anyone know how to fix "sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError"?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Location.changes_in_location - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Someone else had asked about this error before, but the cause seems to have been different. I'm trying to track product movements between warehouses. This is the code for my models file:

```
from inventory import db
from datetime import datetime

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    product_movements = db.relationship('Movement', backref='item', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name} added."

class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    changes_in_location = db.relationship('Movement', backref='location', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.location} added."

class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} units of {self.product} moved from {self.from_location} to {self.to_location} at {self.timestamp}."
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding the relationship in models for multiply relation and specify the **ForeignKey** and **primaryjoin** in the relationship.

```py
lass Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

    from_locations = db.relationship('Movement', backref='location', lazy=True, primaryjoin='Movement.from_location_id == Location.id')
    to_location = db.relationship('Movement', backref='location', lazy=True, primaryjoin='Movement.to_location_id == Location.id')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.location} added."

class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    from_location = db.relationship('Location', backref='from_locations', lazy=True, foreign_keys=[from_location_id])
    to_location = db.relationship('Location', backref='to_locations', lazy=True, foreign_keys=[to_location_id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} units of {self.product} moved from {self.from_location} to {self.to_location} at {self.timestamp}."
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Your solution didn't work initially, but then it did after I changed the backref values in the Location class(both read 'location' in this).

Comment: Ok. I run this code and not have error. but if you have question i'm happy to answer it and help